# How do I match results to MySQL value in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, admin, login-script

I am attempting to build an admin panel where an administrator can view ONLY the records of users that have identical values in a table column called `School`. The table is called users and has both the admins and regular users in it. So when the administrator from `School X` logs in, he should only see the existing records records from `School X`. I am lost on how to do this.

```
<?PHP
require_once('../lib/connections/db.php');
include('../lib/functions/functions.php');
include('../lib/functions/ps_pagination.php');

checkLogin('1');

$getuser = getUserRecords($_SESSION['user_id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE level_access != 1 and School ='$School'"; 
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if ((mysql_num_rows($res)) > 0){
    $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 10, 5, "");
  ?>

<td><?=$row['username'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];?></td>
```

I know the problem is somehow defining the admin's `school` variable and matching it to the user's `school` variable.

Comment: where is the values for $School coming from ? what exactly is not working here? Is users the only table that you have ?

Comment: yes, users is the only table that i have. Where the School value is coming from is exactly what I need help with. It is in the table 'users' in the School column, but I don't know how to pull the value from the table for the logged in admin.

Comment: are you able to get the username for the logged in user from the users table ?

Comment: yes, i am able to use: <?php {echo $getuser[0]['first_name']." ".$getuser[0]['last_name'];} ?> to get the username for the logged in user.

Comment: then you can write another query before your current $sql that gives you the name of the school for the logged in user. You can then pass that value for school to your current query to get list of all the users for the school to which the logged in user belongs. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Cant you make another row in the table and call id: "Admin"? Put yes when the person is admin and check wether the the row "Admin" of the person is "yes" or "no". If it's yes, he can see the records. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Maximus2012, that makes perfect sense. However, that's the code that I cannot figure out.

Comment: Loko, I am able to see the records when the person is an admin no problem. The problem is that I see all the records, but I only want the records that have matching values in the 'School' column.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE level_access != 1 and '".$getuser[0]['School']."'=School"